# Yocto included cmake-project can't find stdio.h

Tags: c, cmake, yocto

I'm trying to include a cmake-project into my yocto-build. For this I have bundled the cmake-project into a .tar.gz-file and created a recipe.

The recipe looks like this:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Library for foo"
SECTION = "utils"
LICENSE = "closed"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=eeafce4ba9a6b4ae7a5367c3b26e0182"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/foo:"
SRC_URI = "file://foo.tar.gz"
S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit pkgconfig cmake
```

When trying to build the image with bitbake, the compilation of `foo` fails:

`foo.c:2:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory`

It seems like the compiler can't find the necessary headers. How do I fix this?

Comment: You should include your build files, at least CMakelists.txt, and maybe the build log: what is the actual compile command that gets executed

Comment: I know it's an old post, but did you ever solve your issue? I have a similar issue, and struggling to figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see foo.tar.gz.

I guess it contains the CMakelists.txt file as well as the source code?

I don't think it's related to your problem, but in general it would be a good idea to keep your sources and your meta data separate. I would put sources plys Cmakelists.txt in a repo and the OE/YP meta data in some meta layer.